# Pattern for a class that is a list of itself

Tags: scala

Consider the following:

```
object Main
{
  case class Foo(bar: Int) extends FooList {
    val self: List[Foo] = this :: Nil
  }

  abstract class FooList {
    val self: List[Foo]
    def ~(that: Foo) = { val list = self :+ that; new FooList { val self = list } }
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val foo = Foo(1) ~ Foo(2) ~ Foo(3)
    println(foo.self)
 }
}
```

Could this line:

```
{ val list = self :+ that; new FooList { val self = list } }
```

be simplified in any way? I'd like to write something like:

```
new FooList { val self = this.self :+ that }   // won't compile
```

It seems to boil down to being able to refer to differently-scoped identifiers that has the same name. Is there any mechanism for that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This solves the scoping issue. If I understand correctly that's what you want.

```
abstract class FooList { outer =>
  val self: List[Foo]
  def ~(that: Foo) = { new FooList { val self = outer.self :+ that } }
}
```

Answer: **yes**. Self-types can also be used as aliases to outer scopes.