# What does "outer =>" really mean?

Tags: scala

Is there any documentation on the "outer =>" feature? It looks like a self type annotation with an infered type. However I have the feeling that I am wrong.

If it would be the case, is it only a different way to express access to `super`?

```
trait A extends (B => C) {
  outer =>
  def apply(x: B): C = outer(x)
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Not `super`, but the *outer scope*. It's a way to aliasing different scopes. For example:

```
class A(val x:Int) { thisA =>
 class B { 
   val x = 2 
   val y = x + thisA.x // without thisA how could we use A.x instead of B.x ? (*)
 }
}
```

There is a better illustration [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4344172/480674).

(*) There exist another way to have the same effect, but it's beyond this question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How would the outer scope be expanded in the given example? Would outer(x) be the apply method of (B => C)? Or would it be the "this" scope which is the apply method of the trait A? Or would it be D's apply if I do new D with A?

Comment: In both cases, your example and new D extends A, outer() would be outer.apply() from A.

Comment: For those as curious as I was, the 'other way' is A.this.x.

Comment: @dave, you are right. Now, what if there was another A class inside B? :)

Answer (score 6):

It is a different way to access `this`. It is useful in cases where an outer `this` would be shadowed by another `this` in an inner class. That way, you can just give the outer `this` an additional (the original `this` would still be available when it is in scope so it’s not a renaming) name.