# what is the self => used for?

Tags: scala

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does “outer =>” really mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4353915/what-does-outer-really-mean)

When i look in to the source code of: scala/src/library/scala/Option.scala

```
sealed abstract class Option[+A] extends Product with Serializable {
  self =>
```

I wander what the self use for. I know the normal use of self type is to restrict the class the trait can be mixed in. such as:

```
scala> trait A
defined trait A

scala> trait NeedA {self: A =>}
defined trait NeedA

scala> new NeedA {}
<console>:10: error: illegal inheritance;
 self-type java.lang.Object with NeedA does not conform to NeedA's selftype NeedA with A
              new NeedA {}
                  ^

scala> new NeedA with A {}
res39: java.lang.Object with NeedA with A = $anon$1@4d04a0e8

scala>
```

but the "this =>" is not the case. what indeed this "this =>" used for?

Answer (score 6):

It creates an alias to this, which may be handy in inner classes (synonymous for OuterClass.this)

```
class A {self => 
   ...
  class B {
      // self is the enclosing A, synonymous for A.this
  }
}
```